# Why the server not accessing connection variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to retrieve data from database using Node.js restify framework. The server is running fine but when I visit http://localhost:8081/get I get this error:

```
{
  "code": "InternalError",
  "message": "connectionPool is not defined"
}
```

Here's my code:

**server.js**

```
require('./app/core/routes.js');
```

**routes.js**

```
var restify=require('restify');
var fs=require('fs');
var controllers = {};
     controllers_path = process.cwd() + '/app/controllers';
fs.readdirSync(controllers_path).forEach(function (file) {
    if (file.indexOf('.js') != -1) {
        controllers[file.split('.')[0]] = require(controllers_path + '/' + file);
    }
});
var server=restify.createServer();
server.get('/get', controllers.article.printHello);
server.listen(8081, function (err) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);
    else
        console.log('App is ready at : ' + 8081);
});
```

**article.js**

```
var something2=require('../core/connection.js');
something2.something();
exports.printHello= function(req, res, next){
    connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                Error: err,
                Message: "Can't connect Database."
            });
        } else {
            //queries
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM book", function (err, rows, fields) {
                res.send({
                    json: rows
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
```

**connection.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.something = function () {
    var connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'books'
    });
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be correct, `connectionPool` isn't defined, it's defined in a different file, but that doesn't help much ?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: does the console say anything else?

Comment: I don't want to write the connection code in same file. I want to 'include' it.

Comment: CMD console is saying: 'Server is running'. Chrome's console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connection.js file, export the pool

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.connectionPool = function() {
    return mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'books'
    });
}
```

Then use it in your article.js file

```
var conn = require('../core/connection.js');
var pool = conn.connectionPool();

exports.printHello = function(req, res, next){
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) { ...
```

Comment: I'll try and tell you.

Comment: Are you sure it's okay? I'm getting error 'conn.connectionPool()` is not a function.

Comment: You're right, it's whatever `createPool` returns. Wrapped it in a function, try it now.

Comment: Could you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501764/why-is-it-showing-connection-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return` your variable `connectionPool` in your `connection.js`'s `something` function.

**connection.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.something = function () {
    var connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'books'
    });
return connectionPool; // notice here
}
```

**article.js**

```
var something2=require('../core/connection.js');
var connectionPool =  something2.something(); //notice here
exports.printHello= function(req, res, next){
    connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                Error: err,
                Message: "Can't connect Database."
            });
        } else {
            //queries
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM book", function (err, rows, fields) {
                res.send({
                    json: rows
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: @Vikas Kumar I gave you the right answer for the beginning

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have thought so.

Comment: Glad that helped :)

Comment: Do you know about restify and mysql?

Comment: Maybe I could help, what is your question?

Comment: I'll let you know if I face any problem. Can you give your hangout id?

Comment: Can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501764/why-is-it-showing-connection-not-defined