# Why is it showing connection not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use `connection` from a **connection.js** file and use it in different file **webFrontend.js** using `exports` object. Now what I get on running server is:

```
{
  "Result": "undefinedThis is result"
}
```

That means `connection` is not defined. Why is it happening? `connection` is working fine if `getConnection` is created in same (**webFrontend.js**) file, but the problem is when I use `getConnection` in same exports function in **connection.js** hence the `connection` not defined error:

Here are 2 necessary files (routes file has no problem) that explains what I'm doing:

**connection.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.connExport = function () {
    var connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'rockcity_followme'
    });
    if(connectionPool) {
        connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            } else {
                return connection;
            }
        });
    }else{
        var abc="return error";
        return abc;
    }
}
```

**webFrontend.js**

```
var connObj=require('../Routes/connection.js');
var connection=connObj.connExport();
exports.getIndivRecords= function(req, res, next){
res.send({
    Result: connection+"This is result"
});
    return next();
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I don't understand what it has about my question?

Comment: `connectionPool.getConnection` is an asynchronous function. Why do you think it has a callback parameter?

Comment: So is there any way to solve? Would I need it export separately below the connectionPool export?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to solve it. Read the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the `.js` file extension, it's automagically added for you.

The code below uses standard error-first callbacks

**webFrontend.js**

```
var connection = require('../Routes/connection');
exports.getIndivRecords = function(req, res, next){

  // connection takes a standard error-first callback
  connection(function(err, conn){
    if (err) {
      // Handle the error returned
      console.log(err);
    }
    // The database connection is available here as conn
    console.log( "Connection:" + conn);

    // presumably you want to do something here
    // before sending the response

    res.send({
      Result: conn + "This is result"
    });
  });
  return next();
};
```

**connection.js**

```
var mySQL = require('mysql');
var connectionPool = mySQL.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'rockcity_followme'
});
var getConnection = function (cb) {
  connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    // pass the error to the callback
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    cb(null, connection);
  });
};
module.exports = getConnection;
```

Comment: Would it help ?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Amended my answer with the callback for the connection

Comment: What is cb here ?

Comment: cb is a callback function

Answer (score 0):

First of all @Dan Nagle was right no need of `.js`

Second You are getting the connection `undefinded` because still the method doesnt returned with result.

Use promise to call your Connection.js method

Your node is single threaded async execution,
He doest wait for the method to return a result

1) Problem with your javascript is that

```
var connection=connObj.connExport();
```

in Creation stage `connection` was defined by javascript as undefined and as 
`connObj.connExport();` as still not returned with answer 
it executed this function in which connection was undefined

```
exports.getIndivRecords= function(req, res, next){
res.send({
    Result: connection+"This is result"
});
```

Use promise read this first so you can understand something about promise and callback if you are unable to solve than comment i will play with it.But first you try.Thanku

[Understanding promises in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296505/understanding-promises-in-node-js)

Ok Try This I have used promise here

```
var connObj = require('../Routes/connection');
connObj.connExport().then(
    function (connection) {
        exports.getIndivRecords = function (req, res, next) {
            res.send({
                Result: connection + "This is result"
            });
            return next();
        };
    }).catch(function (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
    return;
});




var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.connExport = function () {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    var connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'rockcity_followme'
    });
    if (connectionPool) {
        connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                return fulfill(connection);
            }
        });
    } else {
        var abc = "return error";
        return reject(abc);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What you say about 2nd answer?

Comment: No he is wrong it wont work,this is not the proper way to callback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503828/how-to-return-value-from-this-function/40503859#40503859

Comment: Did you tried my code it will work promise is always better than callback

Comment: ok Good,But you must also read about promise,it will solve your many problems