# How to return value from this function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is code in my node.js project but I can't access the value of `connection2`. I read somewhere that .getConnection is asynchronous function so I can't get the value of connection2 this way. How can I modify this code to properly return the value?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'rockcity_followme'
    });
exports.connExport=function() {
    var connection2;
    connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection2=connection;
    });
    return connection2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return the connection here. It must be asynchronous, so you take a callback as a parameter and call the callback when you have the connection.

```
exports.connExport=function(callback) {
    connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        callback(connection);
    });
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node?rq=1) for more information about asynchronous vs synchronous functions in node.

---

When a function does anything asynchronously, it has to be asynchronous all the way up. To use `connExport` from another module, it must be used asynchronously.

```
var yourModule = require("yourModule");
yourModule.connExport(function(connection) { // <-- the callback function
    // you can use connection here
});
```

Comment: This is what I don't understand. Where should I write/define the callback function? Would you please edit your answer a bit?

Comment: @VikasKumar Does the example usage I added help?